# https redirection not working for home directory

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I'm currently trying to force https for may domain name. Its working for mydomain/wildcard but not for the home url that is mydomain/

I'm using this line for redirection in my .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force HTTPS on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

That will force HTTPs on everything